# Postgis + could not access file "$libdir/postgis-2.1": No such file or directory

Tags: postgresql

I am running postgresql9.3 and postgis2.1 , it works fine. When i installed QGIS by using the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install qgis
```

After installing QGIS the postGis is not working. When i tried to execute a spatial query, it shows error:

```
 could not access file "$libdir/postgis-2.1": No such file or directory
```

SO  i uninstalled QGIS , but now also i get the same error. I searched a lot regarding this, i cant find the solution. Help me to solve this. Thanks in advance..

Comment: I solved the problem .. I reinstalled libgdal and postgis .. it works fine now..

Answer (score 7):

You can reinstall the postgis extension for PostgreSQL, it worked for me :

```
sudo apt-get install postgresql-9.3-postgis-2.1
```

Comment: same in OS X `brew uninstall postgis` - `brew install postgis`

Comment: This does not solve the issue. Only perpetuates it.

Comment: Thank you so much. Saved my S literally

Answer (score 5):

Reinstalling postgis may solve some cases, but I got the same error after Postgis was updated to 2.2. If that's the case, you'll also need to go into your SQL editor of choice run:

```
alter extension postgis update to "2.2.0";
```

I believe this needs to be run as the `postgres` user. (My preference is to do this is via `psql -d my_database -U postgres`.)